# I'm working on python gui project and i want to flood my ComboBox with Mysql data

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Here's my code. I'm using a method levelcombobox to flood my combobox

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    database="efs"
)
e3 = Combobox(frame2, font=bFont, width=18).grid(row=3, column=2)

Select="select distinct(level) from table1"
mycursor.execute(Select)
result1=mycursor.fetchall()
e3["values"] = result1
```

I am new to the python gui. Correct me if i could optimise more to this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looping through the `result1` and saying `e3['values'] = result` where result is each value in `result1`

Comment: error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `e3` is not a list, right?

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

then do the following

```
Select="select distinct(level) from table1"
mycursor.execute(Select)
result1=mycursor.fetchall() #a list of tuples
```

Add ttk before Combobox

```
e3 = ttk.Combobox(frame2, value=result1).grid(row=3, column=2) #populate
```